Google sign with flutter error firebase_auth/provider-already-linked
I'm using flutter and google sign in through firebase ( mobile app) with laravel backend, the app is connected through api website url
the issue is when i login with google auth it works well and when i logout i cant login again i got this error msg in android studio terminal firebase_auth/provider-already-linked]?
if i delete the user from my back end db i can login again
here is my code if anyone has an idea ?
Future<User> signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();

if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final UserCredential authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final User user = authResult.user!;

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);

  final User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  try {
    AuthCredential emailAuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: user.email!, password: DEFAULT_FIREBASE_PASSWORD);
    user.linkWithCredential(emailAuthCredential);
  } catch (e) {
    log(e);
  }

  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  return user;
} else {
  appStore.setLoading(false);
  throw USER_NOT_CREATED;
}

}

I think you only signed out from Google Sign-In. You also have to sign out from the Firebase Auth instance.
try this  in your code ,
await googleSignIn.signOut();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();

You can also refer my code below

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<void> googleSignOut() async {
  try {
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _auth.signOut();
  print('Signed out successfully');
  } catch (e) {
  print('Error signing out: $e');
 }
}


Thanks for taking time to answer unfortunately even after adding the code you mentioned it still throwing this error Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/provider-already-linked] [ERROR_PROVIDER_ALREADY_LINKED] - User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider. unless i delete the user from my backend database it will work again

Anyone here could help ?
